# Using completion function in Term::ReadLine::Gnu

Tags: perl

I want to make a console and change the automatic completion function when I press tab but I want to differentiate between two cases:

1. If I press tab and the beginning of the command matches a list I supplied in an array, the auto complete will be according to this array.
2. If I press tab and the command isn't recognized from the list I supplied, I want the generic completion function to work, so t hat it will auto complete directories and file names in the current directory.

Is it possible?
Thanks a lot.

Edit: I'm trying to do it inside a perl script. I saw this example:

**rl_attempted_completion_function**

A reference to an alternative function to create matches.

The function is called with TEXT, LINE_BUFFER, START, and END. LINE_BUFFER is a current input buffer string. START and END are indices in LINE_BUFFER saying what the boundaries of TEXT are.

If this function exists and returns null list or undef, or if this variable is set to undef, then an internal function rl_complete() will call the value of $rl_completion_entry_function to generate matches, otherwise the array of strings returned will be used.

The default value of this variable is undef. You can use it as follows;

```
use Term::ReadLine;
...
my $term = new Term::ReadLine 'sample';
my $attribs = $term->Attribs;
...
sub sample_completion {
    my ($text, $line, $start, $end) = @_;
    # If first word then username completion, else filename completion
    if (substr($line, 0, $start) =~ /^\s*$/) {
        return $term->completion_matches($text,
                                         $attribs->{'username_completion_function'});
    } else {
        return ();
    }
}
...
$attribs->{attempted_completion_function} = \&sample_completion;
```

completion_matches(TEXT, ENTRY_FUNC)

What I want to do is that in case when tab is pressed it recognizes a substring from an array I provide, the auto completion will be from that array (if there are multiple matches it will give all of them like a regular unix console).
Otherwise, I want the auto completion to be file recognition.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Term::Bash::Completion::Generator](http://p3rl.org/Term::Bash::Completion::Generator)?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in a perl script. I saw an example like this one:

Comment: Is it not possible to point `rl_completion_entry_function` to your custom subroutine, then call `filename_completion_function` directly from your subroutine in case no match is found?

Comment: Can you please write the exact syntax I need to use to call filename_completion_function?

Comment: Something like `Term::ReadLine::Gnu->filename_completion_function( $text, 0 )` works. There is probably a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subroutine used internally by `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` to provide the default completion is `filename_completion_function`, which you can call directly from your custom subroutine:

```
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term = new Term::ReadLine 'MyTerm';
$term->Attribs->{'completion_entry_function'} = \&my_completion;
my $ans = $term->readline('How can I help you? ');

sub my_completion {
    my ($text, $state) = @_;
    if (my_test) {
        return my_custom_stuff;
    }
    else {
        return Term::ReadLine::Gnu->filename_completion_function($text, $state);
    }
}
```

Comment: This brings me closer to a solution but I want when I try to auto complete a file that if there are several matches, I will get a list with the options, but the solution here auto completes only the first file match it finds, and ignores other files starting with the same name, like a regular unix console. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: @user3636583, Are you sure you unpacked `$state` and passed it on to `filename_completion_function` as shown? If so, I cannot help you with this--in my version of `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`, it just works.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my version and now it seems to work. Now I'm having problems with the first part of the if condition:
I want to provide an array, that if I go into the first part of the if condition the console will auto complete, in the same way as the second part of the if, the elements from the array that begin with the attempted completion. How can I do that?